# Why is the "Add Accessory" View Controller presented after long delay?

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I have the problem that the `Add Accessory View Controller` (Figure 2) is presented about 6 seconds after I pressed `Add Anyway` in the `Add HomeKit Accessory Alert` (Figure 1) which is waaay to long. *(Xcode 8.2 beta, Deployment Target: 10.0, Device iOS: 10.1.1)*

The code is fairly simple:

`home` is a `HMHome`
`accessory` is a `HMAccessory`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    defer {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    let accessory = accessories[indexPath.item]

    home.addAccessory(accessory) { error in
        // ...
    }
}
```

I already tried wrapping the code in `DispatchQueue.main.async { /**/ }` but that does not fasten the presentation up.

---

**Is this just an issue because the Accessory is not (yet) certified or did I forget to configure / wait for something before I can call `addAccessory` safely?**

*Note: I have the same issue when adding the Accessory in the [HomeKit example provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)*

---

`Figure 1: Add HomeKit Accessory Alert`
[image: Add HomeKit Accessory Alert]

`Figure 2: Add Accessory View Controller`
[image: Add Accessory View Controller]

Comment: This is not an issue it is taking time to prepare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I updated the firmware of the Bridge.